# Что такое %PUBLIC_URL%?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, веб-программирование, href

Встретил на https://github.com/Archakov06/react-todo/blob/master/public/index.html синтаксическую конструкцию `%PUBLIC_URL%`.

1. Что она означает и
2. к синтаксису какой технологии (фреймворка, библиотеки или языка) относится? И зачем она используется, если в href можно задать `./relative_path` или `../relative_path`?

Comment: Там же всё написано: что это, для чего и почему

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Что это и для чего понятно. А почему нет.

Comment: Написано. Читаем внимательно: `Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский извините меня за мою непонятливость. Можете разъяснить смысл последнего предложения?